Metpy error - AttributeError: `np.unicode_` was removed in the NumPy 2.0 release. Use `np.str_` instead
Basic python with numpy 2.0 is throwing a big error. I thought metpy 1.6 fixed numpy 2.0 issues. Is anyone still having this?  Thanks.
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Code:
#!/home/ccc/miniconda3/bin/python
import numpy as np
from metpy.units import units
distance = np.arange(1, 5) * units.meters

Execution (error code):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ccc/t1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from metpy.units import units
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/metpy/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 27, in <module>
    import xarray as xr
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xarray import testing, tutorial
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/testing.py", line 10, in <module>
    from xarray.core import duck_array_ops, formatting, utils
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/duck_array_ops.py", line 36, in <module>
    from xarray.core import dask_array_ops, dtypes, nputils
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/dask_array_ops.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xarray.core import dtypes, nputils
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/dtypes.py", line 43, in <module>
    (np.bytes_, np.unicode_),  # numpy promotes to unicode
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccc/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 400, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: `np.unicode_` was removed in the NumPy 2.0 release. Use `np.str_` instead.


If you look carefully at the traceback, you can see that this error is coming out of xarray code, not metpy. It looks like this problem is identical to this issue and fixed by this Pull Request. You should be able to fix this in your environment by making sure xarray >= 2023.09.0 is installed.
